# Need to Dynamically Pivot Table Making Date Column New Table Headers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I've seen just about every kind of pivot example on the Internet, both text based tutorial and video. Not one is solving the issue at hand.

What I want is to pivot the following table:

**Sales Table**

```
    SalesId  | SalesDate   | SalesLocation  | SalesAmount
    -----------------------------------------------------
     1       | 2012-03     | New York, NY   | 3,000
     2       | 2012-04     | Miami, FL      | 2,500
     3       | 2012-05     | Carmel, CA     | 2,850
     4       | 2012-06     | Berkeley, CA   | 1,900
     5       | 2012-07     | Akron, OH      | 4,200
     6       | 2012-08     | Portland, OR   | 2,200
```

I would like to PIVOT this table to show each row as a **column**, not distinct SUM of columns. Each row is specifically it's own column, with the date as the **header**, as if the table has been turned 90 degrees clockwise like an Excel spreadsheet, for date forecasting:

```
    Account Info    | 2012-03      | 2012-04     | 2012-05     | 2012-06
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    SalesId         | 1            | 2           | 3           | 4
    SalesLocation   | New York, NY | Miami, FL   | Carmel, CA  | Berkeley, CA
    SalesAmount     | 3,000        | 2,500       | 2,850       | 1,900
```

Most of the tutorials on this subject involve creating sums of several rows that have either the same city, the same status or the same type.

For this situation, each row already has a distinct unique date that will never be duplicated, so all records are unique and therefore do not require a function like **SUM**.

So far, after viewing an incredibly clear solution by JoyceW on the [PIVOT Using Date Column](https://forums.asp.net/t/2027298.aspx?PIVOT%20using%20Date%20Column%20) thread at the ASP.net forums, I have gotten this far:

```
    declare @cols varchar(max)

    select @cols = (select distinct SalesDate from SalesTable for xml path(''))

    select @cols = replace(@cols, '', '[')
    select @cols = replace(@cols, '', '],')
    select @cols = left(@cols, len(@cols) - 1)

    declare @query varchar(max)

    select @query = 'select * from (select SalesId, SalesLocation, SalesAmount 
    from SalesTable) src pivot (max(SalesAmount) for SalesDate in ('
    + @cols + ')) piv;'

    execute(@query)
```

While this is not what I was looking for, it's the only tutorial that has allowed me to actually return a result set where the top columns are actually the **dates** (yay), as seen below:

```
    SalesId | SalesLocation  | SalesAmount | 2012-03 | 2012-04 | 2012-05 
    1       | New York, NY   | 3,000       | {null}  | {null}  | 4
    2       | Miami, FL      | 2,500       | {null}  | 3       | {null}
    3       | Carmel, CA     | 2,850       | {null}  | {null}  | {null}
    4       | Berkeley, CA   | 1,900       | 1       | {null}  | {null}
    5       | Akron, OH      | 4,200       | {null}  | {null}  | {null}
    6       | Portland, OR   | 2,200       | {null}  | 2       | {null}
```

Not really sure what's going on here, but it's a lot closer than I was before, I'm actually receiving a result set. Any ideas about how to fine tune this where the rows showing up need to be rotated or pivoted as well?

It seems that I'm only pivoting the headers and not the entire table as I would like. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `select @cols = (select di` is not Oracle syntax, it is SQL-Server. Please correct tags in your question, so you will get help faster.

Comment: Does my answer works for you? or you are looking for something else?

Comment: @CuriousKid I'm actually trying it right now. Will send a message (and solution vote) as soon as I'm finished. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want multiple aggregation columns in your pivot you have to do the iterations for each aggregation value. I am using `Sales` as the table name. Please change the table name if it is different for you. Below query should give you the result you want.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Convertcols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @SQL  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @PivotColumn Varchar(100),
    @i Int = 1,
    @AggColumn Varchar(100)
DECLARE @Columns TABLE (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), AccountInfo Varchar(max))

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ', '+ QUOTENAME(SalesDate)
                    from Sales
                    group by SalesDate
                    order by SalesDate
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SELECT @Convertcols = STUFF((SELECT  ', CAST( '+ QUOTENAME(SalesDate) + ' AS VARCHAR(max)) AS ' + QUOTENAME(SalesDate)
                    from Sales
                    group by SalesDate
                    order by SalesDate
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

INSERT INTO @Columns
SELECT C.name  
FROM SYS.COLUMNS C
INNER JOIN SYS.TABLES  T   ON C.OBJECT_ID = T.OBJECT_ID
WHERE T.NAME = 'Sales'
AND C.name <> 'SalesDate'

While @i <= (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM @Columns)
BEGIN 
SELECT @AggColumn = AccountInfo FROM @Columns Where ID = @i

set @query = 'SELECT AccountInfo,' + @Convertcols +
             ' FROM 
             (
                SELECT ''' + @AggColumn + ''' AS AccountInfo, SalesDate, '+ @AggColumn +' 
                FROM Sales
            ) X
            PIVOT 
            (
                Max('+ @AggColumn +')
                FOR SalesDate in (' + @cols + ')
            ) P '


SET @SQL = CONCAT(@SQL, CHAR(10), CASE WHEN @i = 1 THEN '' ELSE 'UNION ' END, CHAR(10) , @query) 
SET @i = @i+1  

END 

EXECUTE (@SQL)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Great design pattern. However, when I run this query (after modifying it to to my db column properties), due to the INSERT command, I'm only seeing the "xx rows affected" message and not the output that you have shown on your image attachment.

Comment: can you show what you modified? What does it show on the Results Pane
?

Comment: Simple typo on my end. This works. This was a great assistance. Please PM me.

Comment: Thanks! Glad to Help. If this worked and you are satisfied with the answer then accept this as answer so it will help others too.

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to be able to PIVOT, you'll need to have at least one non-pivoted column - something which your model is lacking.

> Documentation: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Am I able to use the primary key as an aggregate table? I am almost in understanding that the aggregate table is used as a pivot marker or an column of order.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "aggregate table", though, though you can use any column which won't get pivoted as the base for a PIVOT table.